# How do I prevent video buffering on client device when delivered from IIS7

Tags: iis, video, encoding, youtube

Background: 
a. Running IIS7 on Windows 7 (MIME Type set up for mp4 as video/mp4)
b. Using Premier Pro I have exported a short video as H.264 with YouTube Preset 1280 X 720, 29.97fps
c. Resulting MP4 file is hosted on my IIS Server as A.mp4
d. I upload A.mp4 to YouTube; once processed, I then download both a medium quality and high quality version back and store it on the same IIS Server as Med.mp4 and High.mp4 
e. Accessing the three videos via PC (Chrome), and two Android devices (Samsung Galaxy SII, and Samsung Note 8) A.mp4 consistently stalls during playback (I assume buffering) on all three devices whilst no such stalling occurs on Med.mp4 and High.mp4.
f. A.mp4 and High.mp4 comprise the following: 
Stream 0
Type: Video
Codec: H264 - MPEG-4AVC (part 10) (avc1)
Resolution 1280x720
Frame Rate: 23.976040
Decoded Format: Planar 4:2:0 YUV

Can anyone advise what it is I am missing here? The files A.mp4 and High.mp4 seem to be identical in format and encoding and yet A.mp4 keeps stalling on all client test devices.

Many thanks and regards